# Find the minimum number of colors to color any Map on Torus.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, coloring

I am finding the minimum number of colors to color any map on [torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_graph).

I have drawn how complete graph $K_5$ can be embedded on a torus.

[image: Embedding of K5 on Torus]

I know that the chromatic number of this graph is $5$ and we define the **chromatic number** as the *smallest number of colors needed to color the vertices of so that no two adjacent vertices share the same color*.

I want to know how the embedding of $K_5$ on torus implies that we need more than four colors to color any map on torus.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you construct the dual graph to your embedding (so that each vertex is the capital of a country) then you will see five countries each of which shares a border with all the others.

You may need as many as seven colors, The dual graph is $K_7$.

[image]

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TorusColoring.html